# How much deadlier are enemies when Ascension is active?

Tags: slay-the-spire

The descriptions for Ascension levels 2, 3, and 4 say they make different types of enemies deadlier. (normal enemies, Elites, and Bosses respectively). The [Slay the Spire Wiki](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Ascension) says this means enemy attacks deal more damage.

How much more damage do enemies deal when Ascension is active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no set amount of damage increase for any specific Ascension level.

Different enemies just have different buffs depending on the Ascension,
For example the [Small Spike Slime](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Spike_Slime#Spike_Slime_(S)) deals 1 more damage on A2, but the [Medium](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Spike_Slime#Spike_Slime_(M)) and [Large](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Spike_Slime#Spike_Slime_(L)) each do 2 more damage on A2.

Then there are enemies that don't do any additional damage, but have changes to their buffs, for example the [Cultist](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Cultist) always does 6 damage, but on turn 1 they give a different Incantation depending on your Ascension level.